# Подскажите библиотеку javascript которая добавляет команду паузы кода

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста подскажите библиотеку javascript которая добавляет команду паузы кода, например как в языке программирования lua:

```
wait(10) -- команда паузы в lua.
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать свою

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function delayedGreeting() {
  console.log("Hello");
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log("World!");
}

delayedGreeting();
```

Comment: delayedGreeting();    - забыл .catch асинхронный код без catch уже по сути ошибка.

Comment: @EugeneX Да подобное решение само по себе не идеальное, чего уж тут. Никогда раньше не задумывался как в js тормозить код, как то, не приходилось прибегать, в отличии от других языков. В bash чаще всего использовал, чтоб огромный массив информации в консоли слишком быстро не пролетал и юзер успевал прочесть его.

Answer (score 0):

Как таковая пауза в js невозможна, ибо это категорический противоречит 3й заповеди - **"не блокируй!"**.

Заповеди на русском: https://itvdn.com/ru/blog/article/10commandments-nodejs

Но в ES6 используя async есть некоторый небольшой обход этого правила, который по сути не нарушает заповедь и даёт похожий результат.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  })
}

async function main() {
  console.log(1); // Один
  await sleep(2000); // спим 2 сек
  console.log(2); // Два
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Какая-то статья с вредными советами... Ну или полувредными. И местами устаревшими.

Comment: Просто это единственное что на русском нашел по английский это называется javascript commandments а вот в русскоязычном сегменте что-то я не нашел все заповеди JS'а.

Comment: Тем не менее, статья какая-то вредительская. Код в ней ужасен, причём весь. И сами советы вызывают вопросы. А текст похож на кривоватый перевод. Хочешь, задай отдельным вопросом, разберу её подробно.

Answer (score 0):

Моё решение (без библиотеки), которое работает:

```js
function sleep(Delay_In_Miliseconds) {
  return new Promise(pass_any => setTimeout(pass_any, Delay_In_Miliseconds));
}
console.log('hi')
sleep(15000)
console.log('bye')
```

Код может не работать локально.
(код похож на остальные)

EDIT: Новый код внизу.

```py
function sleep(Delay_In_Miliseconds) {
  return new Promise(pass_any => setTimeout(pass_any, Delay_In_Miliseconds));

}
console.log('hi')
await sleep(150)
console.log('bye')
```

Comment: Функция sleep может и работает, а вот пример использования некорректный, потому что отсутствует then или await

Comment: Обновлено:
```python
function sleep(Delay_In_Miliseconds) {

  return new Promise(pass_any => setTimeout(pass_any, Delay_In_Miliseconds));

}

console.log('hi')

await sleep(150)

console.log('bye')

```

EDIT: Извините, Stack Overflow перенёс всё :D