# Реализовать функцию sleep JS

Tags: javascript

Необходимо написать функцию sleep, как, например, в Python.

Она должна работать так:

```
console.log(1);
sleep(3000);
console.log(2);
```

Это должно выводить 1, а через 3000 мс 2, однако вкладка браузера зависает.

Сейчас я использую этот код,  но он не работает:

```
function sleep(time){
    var isReady = false;
    setTimeout(function(){
            isReady = true;
    }, time);
    while(!isReady);
}
```

Comment: Нельзя. Никак. Вообще. И не нужно.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, можно ж, просто на время ожидания вкладка будет виснуть

Comment: Максимум, что вы можете сделать без зависания, это просто вызвать какой-то код через время `setTimeout(function() { console.log(2) }, 3000);`, формируя нужную функцию.

Comment: Уже был же такой вопрос

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1368921/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский этот дубликат не соответствует хотелке автора

Comment: @andreymal хотелка - это с блокировкой UI?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal понятно, тогда надо голосовать за переоткрытие)) ааа. я смог сам))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let sleep = ms => new Promise(res=>setTimeout(res,ms));

async function fx(){
  console.log(1);
  await sleep(3000);
  console.log(2);
}

fx();
```

Если блокировка страницы не смущает, этот код будет работать:

```js
let sleep=ms=>{
  let d=Date.now();
  while(Date.now()-d<ms){}
}

console.log(1);
sleep(3000);
console.log(2);
```

Comment: Не соответствует условию

Comment: Чтобы вкладка не зависала, необходимо не блокировать выполнение скриптов на странице. В коде автора страница зависнет не на 3 секунды, а навсегда, пока не закроется браузер. Бесконечный цикл блокирует в том числе и выполнение setTimeout().

Comment: @andreymal А вот так по условию? `console.log(1); let d=Date.now(); while(Date.now()-d<3000){} console.log(2);`

Comment: Да, но пользователю сего кода подготовят персональный котёл в аду ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal точно, исправил. На мобильном телефоне не так удобно набирать код, а при ночном режиме на черном фоне не виден черный курсор.

Comment: Спасибо! Решил мою проблему!